# How do I re-publish an app on the Android Market

Tags: android

How do I re-publish an app on the Android Market, do I have to upload all the screen shots again or can I just upload the app?

Cheers,

Mike.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just upgrade your current existing app in the market you can just push your new apk with the same keystore that you have nothing else needed.

But if you want to republish your application with a new account or something like that you have to do all the stuff that you do before adding description screenshots etc.

Comment: i lost my keystore when i publish at first time, now i want update my apk file, how to proceed please help me.

Comment: Well if you lost your keystore for you app when you publish at first time you need to make another keystore again and republish your application as a new application.You cant update your existing application unless you have the keystore sorry mate.